# can't use the cv2.imwrite function well in python

Tags: python, opencv

Here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

def read(sn,tn):
    #read the source and target file
    source = cv2.imread("./source/" + sn +".bmp")
    target = cv2.imread("./target/" + tn +".bmp")
    #then transfer it's channel to LAB
    source = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    target = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    return source,target

def readresult(rn):
    result = cv2.imread("./ct-result/" + rn + ".bmp")
    result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
    return result

def mean_std(x):
    x_mean, x_std = cv2.meanStdDev(x)
    x_mean = np.hstack(np.around(x_mean, 2))
    x_std = np.hstack(np.around(x_std, 2))
    return x_mean, x_std

def color():
    try:
        os.mkdir("./ct-result")
    except OSError as e:
        print("Directory exists")
    for n in range(1,7):
        source,target=read('s'+str(n),'t'+str(n))
        smean,sstd=mean_std(source)
        tmean,tstd=mean_std(target)

        for i in range(0, source.shape[0]):
            for j in range(0, source.shape[1]):
                for k in range(0, source.shape[2]):
                    source[i, j, k] =  round( ((source[i, j, k] - smean[k]) * (tstd[k] / sstd[k])) + tmean[k] )

        s = cv2.cvtColor(source, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
        print('ct-result/tr' + str(n) + '.bmp'+"  is done")
        cv2.imwrite('ct-result/tr' + str(n) + '.bmp', s)

def recolor():
    try:
        os.mkdir("./recov‐source")
    except OSError as e:
        print("Directory exists")

    for n in range(1,7):
        source,target=read('s'+str(n),'t'+str(n))
        result = readresult('tr'+str(n))
        print(target)
        smean,sstd=mean_std(result)
        tmean,tstd=mean_std(target)

        for i in range(0, source.shape[0]):
            for j in range(0, source.shape[1]):
                for k in range(0, source.shape[2]):
                    result[i, j, k] =  round( ((result[i, j, k] - tmean[k]) * ( sstd[k]/tstd[k] )) + smean[k] )

        r = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)
        print('recov‐source/rs' + str(n) + '.bmp'+"  is done")
        cv2.imwrite('recov‐source/tr' + str(n) + '.bmp', r)
#color()
recolor()
```

I am trying to do color transfer between two images. It runs very well while I am trying to transfer my source image to result image. However I am trying to reverse the step, so I can compare the result image and the recover source image.

Explanations about the functions :

`read()` and `readresult()` function do the same thing only differ on the file it reads is different. `mean_std()` function calculate the mean and std from the image. `color()` and `recolor()` basically do the same thing, the only difference is the formula for the calculation. However here is my problem. I can use `cv2.imwrite()` to write the image into my directory but I can't do the same thing into my `recolor()` function.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is it producing the wrong output?

Comment: it suppose to write the file into the 'recov‐source' directory
but it write nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be wrong. But in `recolor()` function you are iterating source again, as in `color()` function. Aren't you supposed to iterate `result` in `recolor()` function?

From

```
for i in range(0, source.shape[0]):
            for j in range(0, source.shape[1]):
                for k in range(0, source.shape[2]):
                    result[i, j, k] =  round( ((result[i, j, k] - tmean[k]) * ( sstd[k]/tstd[k] )) + smean[k] )
```

to

```
for i in range(0, result.shape[0]):
            for j in range(0, result.shape[1]):
                for k in range(0, result.shape[2]):
                    result[i, j, k] =  round( ((result[i, j, k] - tmean[k]) * ( sstd[k]/tstd[k] )) + smean[k] )
```

Comment: I have tried it , but it didn't work  i think it might be logic error however i still can't figure it out